# HTML checkbox is always checked on pageload

Tags: html, checkbox

How do i set the checkbox as unchecked in the HTML? I tried these and it always loads as checked

```
  <input id="chkBox" checked type="checkbox" />
  <input id="chkBox" checked=false type="checkbox" />
  <input id="chkBox" checked="false" type="checkbox" />
```

I am able to modify the checked property via javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't do anything at all, it's unchecked by default.

```
<input id="chkBox" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: that worked! I will accept it once they let me. Thank you James. :)